# Copy JSON file and load from user database

Tags: sql, asp.net, json

Im working on a project that will be used in a closed environment for events within a school.
The basic idea is to have a JSON file with a bunch of different objects that users who will login through a website will be able to "collect"

```
{
  "Object Type": {
     "Ball": {
       "Red": {
         "Collected": false
        },
        "Blue": {
          "Collected": false
         },
         "Yellow": {
           "Collected" : false"
         }
        }
       }
}
```

The problem im running into is how to store this JSON file "unique" for each user.
If a user logs in they should be able to edit their collection and when they logout it's saved. Each user should have a unique collection that has the same "base template".

Both the amount of objects and users will be upwards in the hundreds.

Im writting the website itself in ASP.NET but cant seem to find any good solutions how to tackle this problem.
The user login will be stored in a SQL server.

Anyone who got experience with similar problems who managed to find a solution? Or would it just be better to change language and datastorage structure.

Comment: Write and build this around a data base. You have tons of great tools and things like gridviews, listviews, data repeaters and all kinds of great tools. I don't really see why json fits here at all? json is a format that can be used say between the browser and the server (ajax calls). Nothing stops you from using json this way. Even simple web methods created in .net will without ANY extra code support SOAP, REST, and json formats - and in most cases do this automatic for you. Thus .net can pull data from the database and spit out json at the end of the day. So build this around a database.

Comment: I will try building it around a database instead.
What would you say is the best way to keep track of what everyone has collected?
If there is hundreds of objects and hundreds of users and the database needs to keep track of what everyone has collected. Should there be a database for each user keeping track of what they have collected?

Comment: Sites for shopping or tracking points for games, or in general a site for accounting, or just about anything? You design a correct relational database. So for customers, then their many invoices and each invoice has say many detail lines with parts etc? Once again a single database to drive that site is standard fair. Each logged on user will also of course be a user in that database. From invoices to complex specs for building a boat with 100's of parts? A database with the correct related tables and data model is standard fair for these systems. Very rare multiple databases are used.

Comment: I mean, even just a system to handle users and their logons? That's part of the database system too. thus logged on users will only get and see their data - the database can thus be driven of their membership roles and their provider key id etc.